# What is `Load "fb"` in xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, configuration

What does `Load "fb"` in `Section "Module"` of `/etc/xorg.conf` actually  do?

---

*Tried  to RTFM and searching first.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Load "fb"` is telling X to load the framebuffer module.

```
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules//libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
       compiled for 1.4.2, module version = 1.0.0
       ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.3
```

*from the freedesktop.org xorg archives*

> ```
>     The fb library is what is responsible for almost all of the software
>     rendering that your X Server might do.
>
>     You're probably mostly spending your time in fbComposite() and its
>     children, which is the Render extension software implementation.  Some
>     drivers have hardware implementations of this, and we're working on
>     making this be the case for more hardware.
>
>     -- 
>     Eric Anholt                     anholt at FreeBSD.org
>     eric at anholt.net                 eric.anholt at intel.com
> ```

On most distros you can locate files like this:

```
$ locate libfb.so
/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.5-5.el7.x86_64
```

And inquire into the package itself about the contents/purpose.

#### What's a framebuffer

So the next question might be, what's a framebuffer. For that look to wikipedia: [Framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer):

> A framebuffer (frame buffer, or sometimes framestore) is a portion of RAM[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) containing a bitmap that drives a video display. It is a memory buffer containing a complete frame of data.[2](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2006-June/016057.html) Modern video cards contain framebuffer circuitry in their cores. This circuitry converts an in-memory bitmap into a video signal that can be displayed on a computer monitor.

In computers, buffers such as this, are used to directly map a region of memory to a display/screen, which has a driver that's monitoring the region. Anything placed into this location is picked up and rendered on the display/screen itself.

For more on frame buffers, please refer to this U&L Q&A titled: [What is a framebuffer device and is it required to obtain a higher resolution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38430/what-is-a-framebuffer-device-and-is-it-required-to-obtain-a-higher-resolution).

#### Reference

- [What is libfb.so responsible for?](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2006-June/016057.html)